# MySQL adding dashes to UUID in a table

Tags: mysql, uuid

Is there a easy way to convert UUIDs from this format

> 5967ca5e6162317eb4a825dcdcde0aea

to this format?

> 5967ca5e-6162-317e-b4a8-25dcdcde0aea

with an MySQL Query? i need to convert over 1000 UUIDs

Comment: mysql or sql server?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
SET @x = '5967ca5e6162317eb4a825dcdcde0aea';

SELECT CONCAT_WS('-',MID(@x,1,8),MID(@x,9,4),MID(@x,13,4),MID(@x,17,4),MID(@x,21,1000))n;
+--------------------------------------+
| n                                    |
+--------------------------------------+
| 5967ca5e-6162-317e-b4a8-25dcdcde0aea |
+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I won't claim to be a MySQL guru but I really wonder why the downvote?

Comment: .....because 99% times people follow the logic ***if i don't understand it, its bound to be wrong - hence downvote***   ---maintaining equilibrium +1

Comment: @Arusu Replace `@x` with your column name?

Comment: Works for me. It just needs some obvious error checking (ignore invalid or null records, detect already formatted values).

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario 'haters gonna hate' ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution

```
// MySQL 8.x
SET @x = '5967ca5e6162317eb4a825dcdcde0aea';
select BIN_TO_UUID(UUID_TO_BIN(@x))
```