# How to format uuid string from binary column in MySQL/MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, uuid

In MySQL/MariaDB the most efficient way to store uuid is in a BINARY(16) column. However, sometimes you want to obtain it as a formatted uuid string.

Given the following table structure, how would I obtain all uuids in a default formatted way?

```
CREATE TABLE foo (uuid BINARY(16));
```

Comment: See [_my uuid blog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The following would create the result I was after:

```
SELECT
  LOWER(CONCAT(
    SUBSTR(HEX(uuid), 1, 8), '-',
    SUBSTR(HEX(uuid), 9, 4), '-',
    SUBSTR(HEX(uuid), 13, 4), '-',
    SUBSTR(HEX(uuid), 17, 4), '-',
    SUBSTR(HEX(uuid), 21)
  ))
FROM foo;
```

Comment: See Oleg Mikheev's answer, it's now much easier to do it in mysql 8.0 using BIN_TO_UUID()

Comment: yeah, don't use this answer any more if you are using MySQL 8.0. Use Oleg's below.

Comment: Optimization: instead of repeating the full `HEX(uuid)` operation 5 times, wouldn't it be faster to `SET @hex = (SELECT LOWER(HEX(bytes)));` first, then reference `@hex` 5 times, and also skip the enclosing LOWER()?

Answer (score 56):

MySQL 8 adds [two new UUID functions](http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-uuid-support/):

- [UUID_TO_BIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid-to-bin)
- [BIN_TO_UUID](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_bin-to-uuid) - this is the one you're looking for

So:

```
SELECT BIN_TO_UUID(uuid) FROM foo
```

Comment: I was wondering if you could just `BIN_TO_UUID(<fieldName>)`, this confirms it. Although, If you are having to do this, you probably passed in the `true` flag to `UUID_TO_BIN`, and so you will also need it get the correct UUID back. I.E. `BIN_TO_UUID( <fieldName>, true )`

Comment: I receive 'Function does not exist' and I have the last version

Comment: If you use uuids without dashes, you can also use the shorter [hexadecimal literal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/hexadecimal-literals.html) `x'uuid'` instead of `UUID_TO_BIN('uuid')`.

Answer (score 21):

In earlier (prior to 8) versions you can create a [function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-function.html) in MySQL like the following:

```
CREATE
  FUNCTION uuid_of(uuid BINARY(16))
  RETURNS VARCHAR(36)
  RETURN LOWER(CONCAT(
  SUBSTR(HEX(uuid), 1, 8), '-',
  SUBSTR(HEX(uuid), 9, 4), '-',
  SUBSTR(HEX(uuid), 13, 4), '-',
  SUBSTR(HEX(uuid), 17, 4), '-',
  SUBSTR(HEX(uuid), 21)
));
```

And then simply use it in your queries:

```
SELECT
  uuid_of(id)
  name,
  age
FROM users
```

And it produces:

> `(c6f5703b-fec2-43fd-8f45-45f06583d450, Some name, 20)`

Comment: I'm sorry but this calculation is wrong, it does not reflect the original UUID.
The UUID `2e9660c2-1e51-4b9e-9a86-6db1a2770422` is shown as `c260962e-511e-9e4b-9a86-6db1a2770422` when querying in MySQL Workbench

Comment: @Alex.H any reproduces? `SELECT hex(uuid_column) FROM ${table}` and then `SELECT uuid_of(uuid_column) FROM ${table}`?

Comment: The `hex(myId)` and `uuid_of(uuid_column)` are actually the same `C260962E511E9E4B9A866DB1A2770422` and `c260962e-511e-9e4b-9a86-6db1a2770422`, however it's not the ID (I believe) my MVC application is generating and saving to the database. It generates `2E9660C2-1E51-4B9E-9A86-6DB1A2770422` which is saved as `C260962E511E9E4B9A866DB1A2770422`. It may be an issue with the MySQL EF Adapter I'm using, because if I query anything using the UUID from `uuid_of` I just don't get anything, but if I use the one from the function I posted above, I do get my records.

Answer (score 9):

If you are looking for the opposite, i.e., how to convert from string to binary, perhaps to do a join or something, this is covered here : [Convert UUID to/from binary in Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753505/convert-uuid-to-from-binary-in-node)

This piece of SQL run on Mysql 5.7 helped lock in the concept for me:

```
SELECT
  LOWER(CONCAT(
    SUBSTR(HEX(UNHEX(REPLACE('43d597d7-2323-325a-90fc-21fa5947b9f3', '-', ''))), 1, 8), '-',
    SUBSTR(HEX(UNHEX(REPLACE('43d597d7-2323-325a-90fc-21fa5947b9f3', '-', ''))), 9, 4), '-',
    SUBSTR(HEX(UNHEX(REPLACE('43d597d7-2323-325a-90fc-21fa5947b9f3', '-', ''))), 13, 4), '-',
    SUBSTR(HEX(UNHEX(REPLACE('43d597d7-2323-325a-90fc-21fa5947b9f3', '-', ''))), 17, 4), '-',
    SUBSTR(HEX(UNHEX(REPLACE('43d597d7-2323-325a-90fc-21fa5947b9f3', '-', ''))), 21)
  ))
```

The output is `43d597d7-2323-325a-90fc-21fa5947b9f3`.

*string -> binary*

So `UNHEX(REPLACE('43d597d7-2323-325a-90fc-21fa5947b9f3', '-', ''))` to convert a UUID to binary during an `INSERT` / `UPDATE` / `JOIN` / `SELECT` whatever, and

*binary -> string*

```
LOWER(CONCAT(
  SUBSTR(HEX(uuid), 1, 8), '-',
  SUBSTR(HEX(uuid), 9, 4), '-',
  SUBSTR(HEX(uuid), 13, 4), '-',
  SUBSTR(HEX(uuid), 17, 4), '-',
  SUBSTR(HEX(uuid), 21)
))
```

Comment: Thanks dude, I copy-paste this multiple times per week xaxa.

Answer (score 2):

The correct result is generated by the script below, the other scrips generated a UUID however not the right one.

```
CONCAT(
    substr(hex(Id), 7, 2), substr(hex(Id), 5, 2), substr(hex(Id), 3, 2), substr(hex(Id), 1, 2), '-'
    , substr(hex(Id), 11, 2) , substr(hex(Id), 9, 2) , '-'
    , substr(hex(Id), 15, 2) , substr(hex(Id), 13, 2) , '-'
    , substr(hex(Id), 17, 4) , '-'
    , substr(hex(Id), 21, 12) 
    )
```

Results running the other scripts generated wrong UUID as per below:

- Expected UUID - `2e9660c2-1e51-4b9e-9a86-6db1a2770422`
- What was generated - `c260962e-511e-9e4b-9a86-6db1a2770422`

As you can see they are different.

Comment: This worked for me too. I tried with MySQL 8 method BIN_TO_UUID or the other methods but it wasn't the correct UUID. I have a C# solution and GUIDs are transformed to HEX and encrypted in base64.

Answer (score 1):

### Here's an alternative using concat_ws

Store raw uuid in a variable @x

```
SELECT @x := hex(uuid)
FROM foo;
```

Use CONCAT_WS and SUBSTR to parse human readable UUID

```
SELECT
  LOWER(CONCAT_WS('-',
    SUBSTR(@x, 1, 8),
    SUBSTR(@x, 9, 4),
    SUBSTR(@x, 13, 4),
    SUBSTR(@x, 17, 4),
    SUBSTR(@x, 21)
  )) AS uuid;
```

Comment: yet another alternative approach here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27039152/mysql-adding-dashes-to-uuid-in-a-table

Answer (score 1):

According to this Jira ticket https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-15854 UUID_TO_BIN and BIN_TO_UUID did not make into the Mariadb Server release 10.5. If you are using this version and under of Mariadb Server you will have to use a custom implementation mentioned above.